# Need help with an implication of the Archimedean Property

Tags: real-analysis

I've gotten myself stuck on an implication of the Archimedean Property, as it is presented in Tao's proof of the Least Upper Bound Theorem. According to Tao, the Archimdean Property entails that for any Real number $M$ and any positive integer $n$, there is some integer $K$, such that $K/n \geq  M$. Can any one show me how to derive this result based on the Property, i.e. for any positive reals $x$ and $y$, is there some positive integer $n$ such that $xn > y$? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in trouble just because of the notations. Heer is another way to say the same thing:

The Archimedean property asserts that for any $x, y>0$,there exists a natural number $n $such that
$$nx=\underbrace{x+x+\dots+x}_{n \text{ terms}}>y.$$

Here, for any $x=\dfrac1n$, $y=M>0$, there exists a natural number $K$ such that
$$Kx=\underbrace{\frac1n+\frac1n+\dots+\frac1n}_{K \text{ terms}}>y=M.$$

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Given $M\in \Bbb R$  and  given $n\in \Bbb N.$

If $M\leq 0$ let $K=1.$

If $M>0$ let $1/n=x$ and $M=y.$ There exists $n'\in \Bbb N$ such that $xn'>y.$ Let $K=n'.$

Perhaps you got confused by the two different uses of "$n$" in the two statements.

BTW. It is possible to extend $\Bbb R$ to a larger ordered field $\Bbb R'$in which all the basic rules of $+, \times,$ and $<$ still hold , but which includes  positive members that are smaller than every positive rational, and hence smaller than every member of $\Bbb R^+.$ Their reciprocals are larger than every member of $\Bbb R.$ Such  an ordered field cannot have the Least Upper Bound Property: If $x$ is any upper bound for $\Bbb R$ then  $\forall r\in \Bbb R\;(2r\leq x),$ so $\;\forall r\in \Bbb R\;(r\leq x/2),$ so $\;x/2$ is also an upper bound for $\Bbb R.$ And $0<x$ so $x/2<x .$ So $x$ cannot be the  $least$  upper bound for  $\Bbb  R.$